# $.get() does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATED!!

The code after

```
   $.get(url, { id: id, action: action }, function(data) {
```

does not fire? Complete method below.

```
   function modifyPermit(id, action) {
    var url = "ajax/permit_modify.aspx";
    $.get(url, { id: id, action: action }, function(data) {
        if (data == "SUCCESS") {
            // Update page
            $.get("ajax/permit_getall.aspx", function (data) {
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_permitList").html(data);
            }).error(function(err) {
               alert(err);
            });

        } else {
            alert(data);
        } 
    });
}
```

Using .Net.

Regards,

Robert

Comment: You have used the variable name `url` when I think you want to use `url_mod` in your `modifyPermit` function.

Comment: change this `$.get(url, function(data)`  to `$.get(url, function(data, status)` I guess your trying to compare the status == 'success' instead of your response data?

Comment: Are you sure your code elsewhere actually calls `modifyPermit()`? Is there anything in the browser console that might give you a clue?

Comment: Thank, changed the URL var!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a wrong variable for the url here (you defined `url_mod` but used `url` in your AJAX request):

```
var url_mod = "ajax/permit_modify.aspx?id=" + id + "&action=" + action;
$.get(url, function(data) {
```

which should should become:

```
var url = "ajax/permit_modify.aspx?id=" + id + "&action=" + action;
$.get(url, function(data) {
```

Also instead of manually having to call the `encodeURIComponent` function for each parameter (which by the way you forgot to do in your second AJAX request) I would recommend you using the following construct:

```
var url = 'ajax/permit_modify.aspx';
$.get(url, { id: id, action: action }, function(data) {
```

This way jQuery will take care of generating the properly encoded url. The same concept could be applied in your first AJAX request. Notice how you could pass as second parameter to the `$.get` function key/value pairs that jQuery will use to construct the proper url.

---

UPDATE:

After having an offline chat with the OP it turned out that the problem was not related to the AJAX code shown in his question but rather with the way he was calling the `modifyPermit` function. It was inside the `onclick` handler of a button without returning false. This in turn triggered a full postback to the server leaving no time for the AJAX request to execute. The correct solution was to return false to prevent the default action of the button:

```
onclick="modifyPermit(1,'a'); return false;"
```

Comment: Many thanks, all! I have corrected the URL var, and also now using { id: id, action: action }.

It now goes to the page permit_modify.aspx, that page writes out SUCCESS, but the alert(data); after that call is not fired? Its like the function(data) is not entered into?

Comment: Fire up your browser developer toolbar. If you are using Google Chrome that would be F12 and navigate to the `Network` tab. Now trigger the AJAX request. You should see it listed there. What does the server respond to? Is it sending a 200 status code? You should be able to see the exact server response and the status code.

Comment: It gets HTTP 200 from permit_modify.aspx, but NOTHING from permit_getall.aspx. It does not even make the call.

Its like the first function(data) is not even entered.

Comment: So this probably means that `data != "SUCCESS"`. Coz that's your condition to trigger the AJAX request to `permit_getall.aspx`. So what's the precise response you are seeing in the Network tab from the  `permit_modify.aspx` script? Please realize that from the information you provided in your question we cannot help you any further. From now on use the javascript developer toolbar of your web browser to analyze and debug what exactly is happening.

Comment: I have added:

$.get(url, { id: id, action: action }, function(data) {
  alert(data);

..to debug. The alert does not fire.

Comment: About to throw my laptop out the window.

Comment: Dude, crap those `alerts`. You should not be debugging javascript with alerts. Look at your FREAKING JAVASCRIPT DEBUGGING TOOLBAR IN YOUR FREAKING BROWSER. You've got a Network tab right there which will provide you with all the freaking information you need. And now if you tell me that you are using the freaking Internet Explorer to be doing web development, I will throw my laptop out of the window.

Comment: Haha! Well, ok, I can remove the alert, no problem. But the freaking network tab does not show the permit_getall.aspx requests. It DOES show a HTTP 200 for the first call to permit_modify.aspx though. Im using Firebug.

Comment: GET permit_modify.aspx?id=4&action=d
 
200 OK
 
localhost:54368
 
7 B
 
[::1]:54368
 
 
8ms
ParamsHeadersResponseHTMLCacheCookies

SUCCESS

Comment: Great FireBug's cool, now look at the response. What do you see there? What does the server return as response body payload to this `permit_modify.aspx` script? Is it the `SUCCESS` text? Precisely the `SUCCESS` text?

Comment: Yes, SUCCESS is the RESPONSE (Thats is what I am printing on the page when all goes well with my code in it). And, STATUS is HTTP 200. So all seems well.

Comment: What does the `alert('data');` show? Is it `SUCCESS`? If so the code should enter your `if` and execute the second AJAX request. Put an alert if you want inside. Is it executed? If it isn't then chances are that `data != 'SUCCESS'`.

Comment: And what really yanks my chain is that the function above, which has pretty much the exact same behavior, works fine.. Thats where I add to the DB. Same code. Actually did a cut n paste.

Comment: The alert(data) does not fire.

Comment: basically, the call is made, but the function(data) { is not entered into.

Comment: The reasons why the `success` callback won't be invoked could be twofold: 1. the server returned a non 2xx status code (you've already ruled that out by looking at the Net tab and seeing that the server returned status code 200 and response body of `SUCCESS`) 2. You have a javascript error (checkout the `Console` tab of FireBug).

Comment: I have updated the question, that is how the function looks now. I am getting ZERO error prompts in Firebug, I got a linking error before but I cleared. The HTTP response is 200.

Comment: What do you see in the `Console` tab of FireBug? Also you could try to subscribe to the error callback of the AJAX request to see if it gets triggered.

Comment: CONSOLE shows only 200 OK for the call to permit?modify.aspx. Nothing else. Not sure about how to subsribe to error callback?

Comment: Checkout the documentation of the `$.get` method here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ . It illustrates how you could subscribe to the error.

Comment: Cool, now inspect the parameters that are passed to this error callback to find out more.

Comment: I updated the code above. I tried adding an ERR variable, ill see if it gives something?

Comment: And what does it give?

Comment: Nothing. But it DOES go in to the error code, so something is definately wrong. Is there no way to capture the actual error? And thanks for your help, you have been amazing.

Comment: Try like this: `.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }`. Now inside the error callback inspect the values of the second (`textStatus`) and the third (`errorThrown`) parameters.

Comment: The testStatus gives "error", the others are not defined. Just tried with the following method (new), it also skips shoing the data alert.


function modifyPermit(a, b) {
// Update page
$.get("ajax/permit_getall.aspx", function (data) {
alert(data);
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_permitList").html(data);
});
}

Comment: How are you calling this `modifyPermit` function? Did you make sure that it is invoked? If you can send me an example Visual Studio solution exhibiting the problem I will immediately tell you why it is not working. I feel that this debugging session over StackOverflow not very useful. I am out of ideas and cannot read your code (and mind) remotely. You could simplify the solution and remove all the noise that's irrelevant to the problem (things like database and other external dependencies).

Comment: Fix found by @darin which tuned out to be simple: just add return false; after the method call on the button. Many thanks to Darin for all the time and effort he put in the helping me solve this issue. Could not have don it without you!

Answer (score 0):

Fix found by @darin which tuned out to be simple: just add return false; after the method call on the button.

```
modifyPermit(1,'a'); return false;
```

Many thanks to Darin for all the time and effort he put in the helping me solve this issue. Could not have don it without you!

/Bob